# Checking Computer Status on Network Using Command Prompt and C

Tags: c, networking, ping

I am making a small project in which i needs to continuously check the status of the computer on the network that whether they are alive on the Network or down at a particular time and I wants to do this using C language (No third party tool). I am totally new to this and searched on net and found that I can `ping` the destination to check whether it is alive or not, so my questions are

1) Can i get any return value from the `ping`, so that i can trigger a value at host side based on the return value from the destination computer?

2) Is `ping` a good method to do this?

If you guys have any other recommendation then do share it.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answers

1) No.

2) Probably not.

## Longer Answers

It sounds like what you want is some sort of "Heartbeat" protocol (recently made infamous by the OpenSSL bug "Heartbleed"). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_%28computing%29

A Heartbeat protocol is essentially a protocol which gives you some "status" about a remote computer. What this actually tells you about the computer depends on how the protocol is implemented. If you are writing it yourself, then it is entirely up to you what it returns.

The `ping` CLI function is a simple wrapper for an `ICMP Echo Request` packet. It will tell you if a computer is able to reply with the `ICMP Echo Reply` packet or not, that is all that it can tell you. (See here for mout about `ICMP` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)

`ping` can not give you any more descriptive return value, so it is probably not what you want to use.

If you want to get some actual data from the remote node, you probably want to implement a very small program that will listen on some port on the remote node. This program can implement you Heartbeat protocol, and return to you whatever values you wish.

For instance, you might create a small program that listened for incoming connections on `TCP` port `5555` and if it received a connection it sent back the contents of some file on the system, or the current time, or anything for that matter.

Be careful though, running a program listening on a port on a computer is a inherently **dangerous** thing to do, and if you aren't careful you will be opening up the remote system to malicious attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Ping just says the machine is alive. It doesn't provide status of the application or service running on the PC. In windows, there is WMI using which you can monitor system status, service & applications. Similar to that, linux has openLMI to monitor system events.